# Drush on Acquia Dev Desktop is terribly slow

Tags: drush, acquia-dev-desktop

I'm running version 2, built Jan 9 2020, on a Windows 10 machine. I'm opening the command line via the dev desktop interface (via the small, black command line icon), and all drush commands run terribly slow. A `drush cr` can take 1-2 minutes, `drush uli` the same. Even a simple `drush status` drags.

I've learned that another colleague has the same issue, but still others don't, so I wonder if something isn't installed correctly. I also have lando installed but not running.

What do I have to do to troubleshoot or solve this?

Comment: This is most likely not a Drush problem, but rather that the shell (Git Bash) is terribly slow at all operations. I suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485059 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835775 

As a quick start, try `export PS1='$'` and see if the speed of Drush improves - taken from the first question above.

Comment: And all of your colleagues have the exact same machines, OS and setup?

Comment: @hansfn - by Git Bash, I assume you mean MINGW64, which is what comes up when I run Git Bash from the start menu. This runs all commands fairly fast. The issue is not in the Git Bash app anyway, it's in the Windows command line that comes up when you click the black launcher button in Acquia Dev Desktop. Also, when I run the export command, I get this:  'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @leymannx, yes, all working with Windows 10 on a PC.

Comment: @Jav Sorry, I forgot that Drush is run in Cmd, not Mingw64 / Git Bash, when using ADD. Then my comment wasn't very useful. I have you tried to increase debug when running Drush - to see where the time is spent?

Comment: @hansfn, sorry I've been away and just got back to this. I am not sure what you mean by increasing debug. Is there a way to log the command line activities/events?

Comment: Doesn't `drush help` tell you that there is a `--debug` option? Try it ;-)